# Setting the font of an element, with jQuery .css() to a Google Fonts font

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fonts

I am setting the style of an `div`, with jQuery, to a font loaded from Google Fonts, but the `div` won't be displayed with that font.

Here is where I load the font, in the HTML code:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Slabo+27px' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

In my JavaScript code, I change this style of the `div` like this:

```
$("#id").css({"font-family": "Slabo 27px, serif", "font-size": "35"});
```

Have a look in this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/8fpkjt58/).

I would appreciate help with how to fix this - thanks :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is what is causing your error:

```
$("#header2").css({"font-family": "Slabo 27px, serif", "font-size": "35"});
```

Change it to:

```
$("#header2").css({"font-family": "'Slabo 27px', serif", "font-size": "35"});
```

Font names with two or more words should be quoted.

Comment: Thanks so much @che-azeh! That makes sense now. I'll accept your answer in 7 minutes :).

Answer (score 0):

CSS property "font-family" needs to wrapped in single quotes because it contains a space.

```
$("#header2").css({"font-family": "'Slabo 27px, serif'");
```

Comment: His code was missing single quotations. That was his error. Do you mean to say my answer needed more explanation?